# How can one get the exact coordinates of a point in a png image?

Tags: ios, png, coordinates, distance, pixel

In the iOS app I am developing the user will move/drag a sort of "ping" at the ends of an object he/she has taken a photo of. This is the ping I've just talked about:

[image]

So as you can imagine the user will put the bottom peak of the ping at the ends of the object while what my app knows are only the coordinates of the center of the ping. So, I need to make a correction and I thought I could subtract the pixel distance from the center to the peak from the center y coordinate. Is that correct? Is there a smarter way to achieve this?

Comment: Try it and see if it works. Note that you can only do one-for-one pixel math if you are displaying the image at full resolution on the screen, and even then you will need to allow for the scale factor of the device (iOS uses "points", which are 2 pixels on a retina device, or 3 pixels on an iPhone 6 plus.)

Comment: I am afraid I haven't understood well what you've said...do you mean I should consider the distance in those points instead of pixels?

Comment: I mean that you will get the location of the image center in points. You will probably need to convert that to image pixels. That will mean allowing for the screen scale, and will also mean handling the case where the image is not displayed at 100% scale on the screen.

Comment: effectively, I don't need the coordinates in pixel. I think points should do well too because then I will use a proportion with a coin to get the real length of the object. So, I think I must re-put my question as: is there a way ti get the difference length in POINTS from the center to the peak?